# How to configure g++ so that x++ is atomic (Ubuntu, openmp)?

Tags: c++, concurrency, parallel-processing, openmp

I have a simple instruction `cout << x++` that is concurrently executed by my threads. I sorted the output then did a uniq-c and indeed the counts are greater than 1 for many values. So that suggests x++ is not atomic. How to make it so ?

Comment: Make `x` a `std::atomic`?

Comment: Tried that and still have an inconsistent output, in case it matters x is a static member variable of type std::atomic_size_t

Comment: Cane you give us a [mcve] of the misbehaving code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`x++` is not the only problem you have.  Streams in C++ are *not* thread-safe, so you have to enclose IO in a critical section.  This will also leverage the problem with `x` not being atomic.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
  int x = 0;

  #pragma omp parallel for
  for(int i = 0 ; i < 10; ++i)
  {
    // Do work
    usleep(100000);

    #pragma omp critical
    std::cout << x++ << '\n';
  }
}
```

Comment: You are right, I've actually discovered that after thinking a while (even if x++ and << were both atomic but in separate critical regions, my 8 threads can first all execute x++, then afterwards print the output one after another which leads to duplicates.)